# React's this with onClick or onChange function

Tags: reactjs

I am calling a function in my react component

```
<button onClick={this.createComment}>Submit Comment</button>
```

Inside my createComment function '`this`' is undefined for some reason

```
createComment(event) {
    console.log('inside createComment')
    console.log('event', event)
    console.log('this', this)

    event.preventDefault()
  }
```

I need to call this.setState inside the createComment function.
How do I get the `this` to be the this of the component??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change this :

```
onClick={this.createComment}
```

---

to

```
onClick={(e) => this.createComment(e)}
```

OR

```
onClick={this.createComment.bind(this)}
```

NOTE :

> As @rafahoro commented :
>
> You should prefer to bind "this" on the constructor:
>
> ```
> constructor() { 
>      this.createComment = this.createComment.bind(this); 
> }
> ```
>
> Using `"onClick={(e) => this.createComment(e)}"` or similar, will
>   create a new function on each `render()` call.

Comment: Either use `arrow function` or `.bind(this)` 

`onClick={(e) => this.createComment(e)}`

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri, thanks

Comment: You should prefer to bind "this" on the constructor:
constructor() {
  this. createComment = this. createComment.bind(this);
}
Using "onClick={(e) => this.createComment(e)}" or similar, will create a new function on each render() call.